# Can't fill textboxes with NULL data after doubleclick to data from datagridview | Conversion from type DBNull to type String is not valid

Tags: vb.net, sql-update, double-click

I created basic sql connected data entry form with .net. There is "save" and "update" button. When double click the data from datagridview, textboxes fill with the selected datas and I can update datas if I need. Sometimes I need to save null datas but when I double click the row which is include null data , I recieve this error "Conversion from type DBNull to type String is not valid.". How can i fix this issue?

I'll share update button and double click code below.

THANKS IN ADVANCE

```
Private Sub update_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles update.Click
        Dim sql As String = "Update TBL_XXX set A = '" & ACB.Text & "',B = '" & BCB.Text & "',C = '" & C.Text & "',D = '" & D.Text & "' Where Query_No = '" & DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value & "' "

        Try


            Dim command As New SqlCommand()

            command.Parameters.Add("A", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Decimal.Parse(A.Text)
            command.Parameters.Add("B", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Integer.Parse(B.Text)
            command.Parameters.Add("C", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Decimal.Parse(C.Text)
            command.Parameters.Add("D", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Decimal.Parse(D.Text)
  
            c.CUD(command, sql)
            list()
            clear()

        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        End Try

    End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellDoubleClick
        A.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value
        B.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value
        C.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value
        D.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value
```

To save null data I use this code

```
command.Parameters.Add("A", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = If(A.TextLength = 0, CObj(DBNull.Value), Decimal.Parse(A.Text))
```

And I tried to use this code for doubleclick

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellDoubleClick
 A.Text = If(A.TextLength = 0, CObj(DBNull.Value), DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value)
```

It didn't work. It seems like has logical issue but I couldn't solve it.

Comment: I would suggest that you do things quite differently. If you are populating a `DataTable` in the first place, bind that to a `BindingSource` and bind that to the grid. When you select a row, get the `Position` of the `BindingSource`, which is the index of the row. Pass the `DataTable` and the `Position` value to the second form, bind the table to another `BindingSource`, set the `Position` and then bind the `BindingSource` to your controls. When you finish editing, because it's the same `DataTable`, the changes will be reflected in the grid. Finally, save all the changes with a data adapter.

Comment: If you're interested in doing it the way I described, I'll post an answer with an example. Doing it that way would mean no null checks at all, because the bindings will take care of that. It also means no saving in the second form. All the saving is done in the first form, using the same data adapter you used to get the data in the first place. You can save changes each time you close the edit dialogue or all in a single batch after making as many changes as you want. It's all much cleaner and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test whether the cell is null or not? You can do like

```
if  DataGridView1.Item("ColumnName","RowIndex").value is Nothing then
  'Do something 
else
   'Do something
end if
```

Comment: I've just tried it like that: A.Text = If(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value Is Nothing, vardiyaCB.Text = 0, A.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value). But It's not working.

Comment: you can simply put A.Text = Nothing. You should pass Nothing to the sql query as well. Don't expect the system will grab Nothing from your A textbox value with nothing. You need to do If / Else as well.

Comment: If the grid is bound to a `DataTable` then "empty" cells will contain `DBNull.Value`, not `Nothing`.

Comment: In datagridview, it is Nothing instead of DBnull. Value. In database, it is DBnull.value

Comment: @YatFeiLeong, that is wrong. In the database it is `NULL`. In ADO.NET it is `DBNull.Value`. If you populate a `DataTable` from a database using a data adapter or a data reader then that `DataTable` will contain `DBNull.Value`. If you bind the `DataTable` to the grid then the grid will also contain `DBNull.Value`. Test it for yourself and see.

Comment: yes, you are right. This is DataGridVIew not data table! DataGridView cell define Nothing as dbnull.. dear..